# Navigation Component - findNavController from ViewPager fragment not work

Tags: android, navigation

I have a BottomNavigation with 3 menu option(Home,Service and More).
Home tab fragment contains TabLayout and ViewPager.

ViewPager has 2 fragment - CurrentDetailFargment and PreviousDetailFragment.

ViewPager Works, After that when I applied click on Button of CurrentDetailFargment  using findNavController() then I get exception.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view)

**Navigate Payment Screen**

```
findNavController().
navigate(R.id.action_currentBillFragment_to_paymentOptionsFragment)
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination XXXXXXX:id/action_currentBillFragment_to_paymentOptionsFragment is unknown to this NavController
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:789)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:716)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:704)
    at com.bses_yamuna.user.home.currentbill.view.CurrentBillFragment.navigateToPayNow
```

**According to exception** - I had not mention 'action_currentBillFragment_to_paymentOptionsFragment' id in my graph. But I had declare it graph. This graph is use with BottomNaviagtion.

Please Let me know that I resolve this issues.

**Activity Layout Section-**

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigationHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint_top"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/menu_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        style="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_colors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_modify" />
```

**Adapter**

```
 class ViewPagerAdapter (fragmentManager:FragmentManager, private val titleList: ArrayList<String>): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT ) {

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return if(position==0)
        CurrentBillFragment()
    else
        PreviousBillFragment()

}

override fun getCount(): Int {
   return titleList.size
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return titleList[position]
}
override fun getItemPosition(value: Any): Int {
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
}
```

}

**Set Adapter on ViewPager-**

```
private fun setupViewPager() {
    val titles = ArrayList<String>()
    titles.add(getString(R.string.current_bill_detail))
    titles.add(getString(R.string.previous_bill_detail))
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, titles)
    mBinding.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager( mBinding.pager)
    mBinding.pager.adapter = adapter

}
```

**menu_navigation.xml-**

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/currentBillFragment"
    android:name="XXXXX.view.CurrentDetailFargment "
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_current_bill">

    <action          
  android:id=
  "@+id/action_currentBillFragment_to_currentBillSummaryFragment"
        app:destination="@+id/currentBillSummaryFragment" />

</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/paymentOptionsFragment"
    android:name="XXXXX.view.PaymentOptionsFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_payment_option"/>
```

Comment: did you resolve this @mukesh

Answer (score 5):

Action should define in that fragment that contains ViewPager and TabLayout.

I moved the action 'action_currentBillFragment_to_currentBillSummaryFragment' in host fragment of ViewPager and TabLayout.

Comment: yes, it works, but actually, I think of is this the right way or not...sometimes I think maybe better to navigate directly by ID in this situations because it might be confusing

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue and figured out that we are making the wrong direction action in the navigation_graph XML file. The navigation action direction should be from homeFragment to PaymentOptoinFragment. Not from the currentDetailFragment to paymentOptionFragment. The same goes for the previousDetailFragment.

Navigation direction in the navigation_graph XML file:

[image: navigation_graph]

Kotlin Code to navigate paymentOptionsFragment from CurrentDetailFragment and PrevoiusDetailFragment:

```js
   //Navigation from CurrentDetailFragment to paymentOptionsFragment
this.@CurrentDetailFragment.findNavController().
navigate(R.id.action_HomeFragment_to_paymentOptionsFragment)

//Navigation from PrevoiusDetailFragment to paymentOptionsFragment   
this.@PrevoiusDetailFragment.findNavController().
navigate(R.id.action_HomeFragment_to_paymentOptionsFragment)
```

Try this and let me know if you still face the same issue!

Comment: I have the exact same problem, navigation is working fine from homeFragment to paymentOptionFragment , but I want to navigate from currentDetailFragment or previousDetailFragment to paymentOptionFragment after click on any widget of these two fragment

Comment: Hi @ShubhamMogarkar, I have already mentioned the solution above. Did you follow this accordingly?
Another thing is that, Could you please share which programming language are you using in your project? and the navigation code?

Comment: yes I am using kotlin. I found the solution that I will post in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This Code is for kotlin**

Make sure that you pass childFragmentManager in the FragmentStateAdapter, as below code.

```
class AdapterTabPager(childFragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle) {
   
}
```

Now write this code into your viewPager's fragment.

```
val yourViewPagerContainerFragment = (this.parentFragment as YourViewPagerContainerFragment )
        yourViewPagerContainerFragment.access_anything_from_view_pager_container_fragment
```